# Computing Explicitly the Atiyah Bundle on an Elliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

From Lemma 16 of the paper "Vector Bundles over an Elliptic Curve" we can restrict to the following case: given a line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{E}(x)$ on an elliptic curve $E$ of degree 1 or 0, there exists a *unique* rank two vector bundle $V$ (up to isomorphism) given by the extension

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_{E} \to V \to \mathcal{O}_{E}(x) \to 0.$$

Here, if the degree is zero, we must further assume the line bundle has a non-trivial section.  In addition, by $x$ I just mean whatever point or points we are twisting by.

My question is, how do we actually compute $V$ in practice?  Do we know under what conditions it splits as a direct sum $V \cong \mathcal{O}_{E} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{E}(x)$?  Perhaps someone can show me a simple example where $V$ is constructed explicitly.

Comment: What kind of explicit construction do you have in mind?

Comment: Well for example, I was wondering if it is known when it will split into a direct sum $\mathcal{O}_{E} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{E}(x)$.  Perhaps I'm not truly grasping what Atiyah's lemma is saying.

Comment: It splits if and only if the extension class is trivial. So, if you start with a non-trivial extension, it does not split.